# Dynamically find which file is including the current file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dependency-management

**Context**

I am auto-requiring all files in a directory structure via

```
# base.rb
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
path = File.join(dir, '**', '*.rb')
Dir[path].each { |file| require File.expand_path(file, __FILE__) }
```

and am calling this snippet through a `require` statement in a separate file, `api.rb`.

**Problem**

This code snippet includes itself (`base.rb`) as well as `api.rb`.

**Question**

Is there a 'clean' way to do this type of auto-requiring while dynamically avoiding including the file that has called the auto-require'er (i.e. `api.rb`)?

Comment: Requiring a file twice, or ten times, won't hurt. Ruby will see the request and will ignore it. Is this causing an error, such as a constant redefinition?

Comment: My underlying motivation is that `api.rb` relies on a number of classes/modules/etc defined throughout the directory structure. So, I use `base.rb` to require all of the files that `api.rb` relies on, and then have `api.rb` require `base.rb`. I want to avoid having `base.rb` require `api.rb` because I want to make sure that `api.rb` has everything defined that it needs before evaluating it. Doing this manually (e.g. filter out `file =~ \api/.rb\`) is relatively straightforward, but I'd much prefer to do this dynamically so I can reuse this code more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when you `require` a file identified by a certain path more than once each subsequent call to `require` will return `false` and the file won't be reevaluated. As a result if your `base.rb`, which `require`s everything else, is itself `require`d, further attepts to `require` it should not lead to a reevaluation.

Let's demonstrate it using an example. Create a `lib` directory with 3 files inside.

```
# lib/a.rb

  require 'base'
  puts :a

# lib/b.rb

  require 'base'
  puts :b

# lib/base.rb

  $counter ||= 0
  puts "Evaluated base.rb #{$counter += 1} times"
  dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  path = File.join(dir, '**', '*.rb')
  Dir[path].each { |file| require File.expand_path file }
```

Execute `lib/base.rb` directly. `base.rb` will be evaluated twice: firstly, when it's executed directly; secondly, when it's `require`d by `a.rb`. Notice, that it is *not* evaluated when it's required from `b.rb`.

```
$ ruby -I lib lib/base.rb 
Evaluated base.rb 1 times
Evaluated base.rb 2 times
a
b
```

Compare with `require`ing it. Now `base.rb` is evaluated once only, because attempts to `require` it in `a.rb` and `b.rb` were preceded by having the file `require`d using the command line `-r` switch.

```
$ ruby -I lib -r base -e 'puts :ok'
Evaluated base.rb 1 times
a
b
ok
```

Comment: My main concern is in not requiring the file that has required the file that does the auto-requiring of the rest of the directory structure. Any thinking on this part? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

[Kernel.caller](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller)
returns the current execution stack as an array of strings. You can avoid
calling require on filenames which you find in that array. Multiple files with
the same basename would trip this up. I don't see a way to get a more precise
list of ancestor files.

```
$ head *.rb
==> A.rb <==
require 'base'
puts :A

==> B.rb <==
require 'base'
puts :B

==> CA.rb <==
require 'base'
puts :CA

==> base.rb <==
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
path = File.join(dir, '**', '*.rb')
required = caller.map { |frame| /^(.+):\d+:in `require'$/.match(frame) and File.basename $1 }.compact
Dir[path].each { |file| required.include?(File.basename file) or require File.expand_path file }
$ ruby A.rb
B
CA
A
$ ruby B.rb
A
CA
B
$ ruby CA.rb
A
B
CA
$ ruby base.rb
B
CA
A
$
```